# closing a tiny box pop up

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

how to close a tiny box pop up and refresh parent in javascript. I am using the below script but not working.

```
var parentWindow = window;
$('#submit-deed-button').click(function() {
    TINY.box.show({iframe:'submit_deed.html', closejs:function(){parentWindow.location.reload()}, post:'id=16',width:500,height:300,opacity:20,topsplit:3, boxid:'tinybox_container'})
});
```

Comment: TINY.box.hide()? Doesnt it refresh the parent

Answer (score 1):

USE:

```
<a href="#" onclick="TINY.box.show({iframe:'photos.php?id=<?php echo $result_set['id'];?>',boxid:'frameless',width:900,height:450,fixed:false,maskid:'bluemask',maskopacity:40,closejs:function(){closeJS()}})"
```

Answer (score 1):

i was able to close the TinyBox using this:

```
window.parent.TINY.box.hide();
```